# Can others lose access to a sharing folder on Google Drive, if you move it to a new folder you haven't shared with anyone?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder

I have shared a folder from Google Drive, that was created and lives on My Drive. Let's call it Folder A.

Folder A is shared with a few people I used to do projects with, but no longer am. I don't want to delete the folder but I don't want them to have access to it anymore either.

So I have created Folder B that also lives on My Drive, and I moved Folder A into Folder B. Now, Folder B is a new folder and hasn't been shared with anyone.

My question is, since Folder B hasn't been shared, do others still have access to the content inside that has been previously shared? Or do they lose access since the initial folder has been moved to one that hasn't been shared yet?

Answer (score 0):

Generally drive will pop up a window to let you know if people are going to lose their shared access.
But yes everyone will lose access to the files, it will only be accessible to those with access to folder B.
Another way to check is to go into the share button and see who is listed there.
Hope that helps